# how to download and run python3.11.4 in linux debian 11

Tags: python, linux, debian, python-3.11

I successfully downloaded the tarz for python3.11.4 but when I enter python it still says I am using python3.9. I am using a chromebook with linux debian 11

I ran the tarball and everything downloaded and is setup but when I exit and go back in oython it says I'm using version 3.9

Comment: run `apt-get install python3 python3-dev` inside your terminal

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to build from source, follow these steps:

1. clone from github master branch or download from [https://www.python.org/downloads/][python.org]

```
    git clone https://github.com/python/cpython
```

2. configure where the final build file will go

```
    cd cpython
    ./configure --prefix=$HOME/python3.9
```

3. build

```
    make
    make install
```

Comment: This works but it installed python3.9 and I need python3.10 or higher

Comment: just download the newer version and change the configure command